# Is double close in strace necessarily bad?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, system-calls

I am training a neural network. Somewhere in my code base, I have a code snippet like the following:

```py
def foo():
    d = {}
    with PIL.Image.open(img_path) as img:
        d["img"] = torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor(img)
    return d
```

This code doesn't cause any problems. However, when I run my program under `strace`, I see that there is a double call of the `close` syscall (below, I omit everything except relevant strace lines):

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "example.tif", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3</tmp/example.tif>
fstat(3</tmp/example.tif>, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9274, ...}) = 0
lseek(3</tmp/example.tif>, 0, SEEK_CUR) = 0
lseek(3</tmp/example.tif>, 0, SEEK_SET) = 0
read(3</tmp/example.tif>, "II*\0\250#\0\0\200\0 P8$\26\r\7\204BaP\270d6\35\17\210DbQ8\244"..., 4096) = 4096

# here some more lseeks and reads are omitted

mmap(NULL, 1765376, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb10bbd000
fcntl(3</tmp/example.tif>, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4</tmp/example.tif>
lseek(4</tmp/example.tif>, 0, SEEK_SET) = 0
read(4</tmp/example.tif>, "II*\0\250#\0\0", 8) = 8
fstat(4</tmp/example.tif>, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9274, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 9274, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 4</tmp/example.tif>, 0) = 0x7feb9e7a4000
munmap(0x7feb9e7a4000, 9274)            = 0
close(4</tmp/example.tif>) = 0
close(4)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(3</tmp/example.tif>) = 0
```

I am worried about `close(4) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)`. We can see that there is a duplicate call to the `close` syscall for some reason. The code works fine though. But still, does this necessarily mean that I have a bug in my code?

---

Upd: if anyone is interested, I have compiled a minimal self-contained example and reported the bug at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7042

Comment: Can you post a step-by-step instruction how you ran this analysis, so we can reproduce the issue? I am mostly asking this because I find the problem interesting and want to learn how you did this.

Comment: @physicalattraction I run it like `strace -e decode-fds=path,pidfd,socket -e trace=dup,dup2,open,close,fstat,lstat,ftruncate,ioctl,write,openat --follow-forks -o /path/to/dir/where/traces/will/be/written/trace --output-separately python my_python_script.py foo bar buzz`

Comment: Upd: if anyone is interested, I have compiled a minimal self-contained example and reported the bug at https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7042

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to find out what causes this. In this particular example it seems OK, but there is room for very subtle errors. Imagine that you have a second thread, which `open()`s a file between the first and second `close(4)`. It is likely, that this file descriptor get fd 4 assigned, and therefore will be closed immediately. This kind of error is a nightmare to debug.

Comment: You were right. My friend has managed to write a proof of concept that uses multithreading and crashes because of this.